# Compiler expecting String where it should be expecting Long

Tags: scala

In this code, the compiler message says it expects "j" to be String, but it's Long based on the type of the parameters in the method.

I added method add to express the types so there should be no inference required. If I remove the + "j" and put a constant, the problem remains. If I leave off the "+ j" it compiles. It behaves like "that.v" is implicitly converting to String. But "v" is clearly a Long in the parameter list.

I will also note why "+". I actually want "|" but the compiler says Long does not support "|". So a hint on how to bitwise or a Long or Int would be helpful. My guess is these are signed, and perhaps there are classes specific to unsigned work that should be used.

I have put the trait a class in an object with same result, which is what I expected. I have tried various imports, like Long, and the result is the same.

I wonder if there is some fundamental problem with the environment, as in the hidden imports. I'm using the latest IntelliJ as I work through code in Odersky. I have the Rational class in another file and it compiles fine.

I am at the end of my rope over something fundamental that is not obvious to a new Scala programmer.

```scala
package com.proclivis.field

trait CommandField[A] {
  def |: (that: CommandField[A]):CommandField[A]
}

class IntCommandField[Long] (val v: Long) extends CommandField[Long] {
  def |: (that: IntCommandField[Long]): IntCommandField[Long] =
    new IntCommandField(add(that.v, this.v))

  private def add (i:Long, j:Long): Long = i + j
}
```

Error:(21, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : Long
 required: String
  private def add (i:Long, j:Long): Long = i + j

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
class IntCommandField[Long] (val v: Long) ...
```

The solution is to remove the `[Long]`.

The current declaration defines a generic class where the generic type is called `Long`. Inside this class `Long` refers to this generic class and has nothing to do with the built-in type called `Long`.

When the compiler sees this

```
private def add (i:Long, j:Long): Long = i + j
```

it sees a `+` operator applied two values of a generic type. Scala defines a generic `+` on all types that takes a `String` so it tries to use that. Since `j` is not `String` you get the error message that you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Following would not implicitly convert `Long` to `String`(you need to remove `Long` type annotation from `IntCommandField`):

```
trait CommandField[A] {
  val v: A
  def |: (that: CommandField[A]):CommandField[A]
}

class IntCommandField(val v: Long) extends CommandField[Long] {
  override def |: (that: CommandField[Long]): CommandField[Long] =
    new IntCommandField(add(that.v, this.v))

  private def add(i:Long, j:Long): Long = i + j
}
```

Another issue in your code:

- If you put `override` keyword before `|:` method declaration, compiler complains `Method |: overrides nothing`. Above code resolves this.

Comment: Ok, so I see several things:

A) the def in the class must match the types of the trait even though the returned value is the class

B) This means the value "v" must be in the trait

C) Don't add the type to the class like IntCommandField[Long]

In hind sight, I should have spotted C, but the compiler error led to a focus in the wrong place. It is not clear what the compiler was trying to do with string, nor clear why it did not complain about C directly. Hm, perhaps it used [Long] as a type variable, and it was left out of new, but it is not clear how the relates to string.

Comment: @MikeJones The compiler does not know the type of `i` so it uses the generic `+` defined on all types. This `+` takes a `String` argument but `j` is not `String` so it gives the error that you saw.